# How to eliminate duplicate quadruplets using hashtable/dictionary? Leetcode 4Sum

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, sum

https://leetcode.com/problems/4sum/

I used python dictionary, an outer 2 loop with 2 inner for loop inside it.
Basically, I find all the possible sums of any 2 array element combinations.
Then I append the found pair of elements to the quadruplets if the pair of element already exist in the hashtable.

The code, however, does not pass the case where nums = [2,2,2,2,2] with target=8:

```
class Solution:
    def fourSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[List[int]]:
        quapl = []
        sumDict = {}
        n = len(nums)
        for i in range(1, n-1):
            for j in range(i+1, n):
                # P : [x, y]
                currentSum = nums[i] + nums[j]
                diff = target - currentSum
                # check if diff is in dict, if not, proceed; if yes, append
                #for pair in currentSum:
                if diff in sumDict:
                    for pair in sumDict[diff]:
                        # notice pair already defined as a pair of arrays
                        quapl.append(pair + [nums[i], nums[j]]) 

            for k in range(0, i):
                # Q:[z,l]
                currentSum = nums[i] + nums[k]
                if currentSum not in sumDict:
                    sumDict[currentSum] = [[nums[k], nums[i]]]
                else:
                    sumDict[currentSum].append([nums[k], nums[i]])
        return quapl
```

[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/y374l.png)]
Can someone explain why the test case failed? And what should I do in general to pass this test case?
Thank you!

The hashtable I use have a average time of O(n^2) and O(n) space, so I prefer keep using hashtable.
But if it has to be a different data structure to past that test case, then swtiching approach would make sense to me.

Comment: Please describe the problem here, not just a link to leetcode.

Comment: Why are you starting the range at `1` instead of `0`? You're skipping the first element of `nums`.

Comment: You eliminate duplicates by making `quapl` a `set()`, and then returning `list(quapl)`.

Comment: Is this really any better than using `itertools.combinations`?  With only 200 elements, there are only 64 million combinations.  That's manageable.